# IndexedSeq and removing multiple elements

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have `mySeq: IndexedSeq[A]` and another `myIncludedSeq: IndexedSeq[A]`, where every element of `myIncludedSeq`, is contained in `mySeq`.

I want to create a new `IndexedSeq[A]` from `mySeq` without all elements from `myIncludedSeq`.

I can't find any nice functional approach for this problem. How would you approach it?

Example:

```
val mySeq = IndexedSeq("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "a")
val myIncludedSeq = IndexedSeq("a", "d", "a")
//magic
val expectedResult = IndexedSeq("b", "c", "a") //the order does not matter
```

Comment: So every item in `myIncludedSeq` has to be excluded only N times? That is why `expectedResult` contains "a" although it is enlisted in `myIncludedSeq`, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All elements from `myIncludedSeq` kind of consume elements from `mySeq`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
val original = IndexedSeq("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "a")
val exclude = IndexedSeq("a", "d", "a")
val result = original.diff(exclude)
// IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(b, c, a)
```

From list's diff doc:

> Computes the multiset difference between this list and another sequence.
>   Returns a new list which contains all elements of this list except
>   some of occurrences of elements that also appear in "excluding" list. If an
>   element value x appears n times in that, then the first n occurrences
>   of x will not form part of the result, but any following occurrences
>   will.

Comment: Ok. I have many times read about `diff`, never used it and it never came to my mind. Thanks.